# Concourse resource `check_every: never` time: invalid duration "never"

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource

Running concourse 6.7.4. The concourse documentation says you can set a resource to never be checked by setting `check_every` to `never` (https://concourse-ci.org/resources.html#schema.resource). However, it results int the following error, `time: invalid duration "never"`. I've tried setting it to `never` as well as `'never'` in the pipeline yml file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like this looks like a v7 feature: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/pull/6386